# Assigning TableCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with assigning `AssociatedHeaderCellID` on a `TableCell`.

I havean extended `GridView` in whose overriden `OnRowCreated` I am creating a cell and adding it to a line of the table thus:

```
newCell = new TableHeaderCell() { ID = "SomeUniqueHeading" };

newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
```

and then trying to add the id of one of the existing cells AssociatedHeaderCellID` a few lines later:

```
existingCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID = new []{ newCell.ID};
```

but when the page renders i get an `HttpUnhandledException` saying `"The cell SomeUniqueHeading listed as an associated header cell was not found."`

I have tried using

```
existingCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID = new []{ newCell.ClientID};
```

but with the same result.

I have had a poke arround on google and no seems really to be doing anything i am not and the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.associatedheadercellid(v=vs.110).aspx) are pretty useless.

Any ideas how i can get this working?

Here's a sample of the ASP markup...

```
<%@ Register TagPreFix="aspex" Namespace="AspExtensions" Assembly="AspExtensions"%>

<aspex:ExtendedGridView ID="linesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLines="None" CssClass="lineTable" ConfigGroupName="lineGridColumns">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="lineHeaderRow" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="alternatingRow" />
    <Columns>
        <aspex:ExtendedBoundField DataField="DataField1" HeaderText="DataField1Header" SortExpression="DataField1" ConfigElementName="dataField1" />
        <aspex:ExtendedTemplateField HeaderText="DataField2Header" Visible="false" ConfigElementName="dataField2">
            ...
        </aspex:ExtendedTemplateField>
        .
        .
        .
    </Columns>
</aspex:ExtendedGridView>
```

Comment: What happens if you try without the ID? I'm a bit rusty here but I think controls with ID's need to be added earlier in the page life cycle.

Comment: Using existingCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID = new []{ newCell } gives me a compile error... Cannot implicitly convert type'...TableCell' to 'string'. If it needs to go in earlier do you know how early?

Comment: Comment out the `existingCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID` for now. See if the page loads. If it does add the new header cell, but not the Associated assignment, see if the page loads. I'm predicting it will fail here. I think you need to add the cell in or around the Page Init event. Read up more on the [ASP.net Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you also include you GridView mark up please.

Comment: @JonP I have thrown some in for you...

Comment: If i comment out my `existingCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID` then the page loads fine whether or not i add in extra header cells.